# Xen for office use and network boot

Tags: virtualization, xen, hypervisor

I'm trying to understand if Xen can fit my needs:

I need to have a Windows 7 image that I can copy to different machines (with different hardware) to have kind of default installation for every new entry in the office and faster replacement.

Is that possible to use the hypervisor for this?

Is that possible to use network boot as well of the hypervisor not to install Xen on every machine?

Edit: Will I be able tu use multiple displays?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if and only if you have installed Xen on every machine on your network that is not a good idea. Xen and other type-1 hypervisors are usually used to multiplex a high-end server into a set of virtual machines. Xen is also known for its para-virtualization technique which is not applicable for Windows.

Have you ever thought of VDI (Virtual Desktop Infrastructure) solutions? It enables you to have all your operating systems on a single machine and transfer the desktop to the clients.

Comment: But then we will need another powerful server that runs a virtual machine server? Or the VDI server is able to load the VM process on local computers? Is it working with multidisplay?

Comment: it depends how many VMs you load. in the VDI case, all vm processes are running on a single machine and only the desktop is moved to the client. What do you mean by multi-display?

Comment: I think there are about 50 computers, I mean that they're now using 2 display, will they be able tu use it anyway?

Comment: For about 50 server, you need a high-end server. By your definition, multi-display is also supported.

Comment: Isn't it better, so, to use the hypervisor on the machines? (If it doesn't work as I thought, what's the hypervisor network boot for?)

Comment: the network boot using the PXE protocol means that a virtual machine on hypervisor can be started using its network interface.

Comment: Running hepervisor on every machine is not a good practice for your case. Which hypervisor you intend to install on your meachines? Vmware ESX or Xen? You cannot use VMware because it needs special hardware. In addition, based on my experiment Xen do not show acceptable performance for windows guests. The network boot using the PXE protocol means that a virtual machine on hypervisor can be started using its network interface. This means that the VM and hypervisor are installed and can be booted using PXE.

Comment: Ok, thank you, do you know if is there any other option for my needs?

Comment: Always thank in stackoverflow by +1 on the answer :-). Why you don't install the OS once and get its image by some tools and move the image to other systems?

Comment: Because all the computers have different hardware.

Comment: So, how many different hardware types do you have? 4? 5? or 6? Cannot you have 4, 5 or 6 different images?

Comment: Think about VDI. It will impress you.

Comment: We do have a quite decent server, but it is running the company's database and I'd like not to charge it with 50 or more VM running on it. Will it be fine even with many machines like this?

Comment: NO, I do not recommend that. For ordinary office users, I propose a high-end server for every 30 users due to my experience.

Comment: I was looking for something without expenses, probably we will keep installing Windows and software on each computer as we go.

Comment: I propose you to install windows and other software once on a machine, take an image and keep that image somewhere. Having 50 workstations at most, you will need 200-300 GB of space. Then use the proper image when you wanna re-install the system again.

Comment: Making the image for each will "double" the time for installing just for the few machines that will eventually need to be restored. It doesn't worth the time. If only the company had bought the same computer... But they were not so "organized" and tidy...